# How to Select the elements of a list so that GCD equal to 1

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list

```
lst = {{-5, -210, -120, 195, 810, 410}, {-5, -180, -103, 172, 695, 
   345}, {-5, -150, -86, 149, 580, 280}, {-5, -120, -69, 126, 465, 
   215}, {-5, -90, -52, 103, 350, 150}, {-5, -60, -35, 80, 235, 
   85}, {-5, -30, -18, 57, 120, 20}, {-5, 0, -1, 34, 5, -45}, {-5, 30,
    16, 11, -110, -110}, {-5, 60, 33, -12, -225, -175}, {-5, 90, 
   50, -35, -340, -240}, {-4, -198, -113, 179, 763, 
   393}, {-4, -168, -96, 156, 648, 328}, {-4, -138, -79, 133, 533, 
   263}, {-4, -108, -62, 110, 418, 198}, {-4, -78, -45, 87, 303, 
   133}, {-4, -48, -28, 64, 188, 68}, {-4, -18, -11, 41, 73, 3}, {-4, 
   12, 6, 18, -42, -62}, {-4, 42, 23, -5, -157, -127}, {-4, 72, 
   40, -28, -272, -192}, {-4, 102, 
   57, -51, -387, -257}, {-3, -186, -106, 163, 716, 
   376}, {-3, -156, -89, 140, 601, 311}, {-3, -126, -72, 117, 486, 
   246}, {-3, -96, -55, 94, 371, 181}, {-3, -66, -38, 71, 256, 
   116}, {-3, -36, -21, 48, 141, 51}, {-3, -6, -4, 25, 26, -14}, {-3, 
   24, 13, 2, -89, -79}, {-3, 54, 30, -21, -204, -144}, {-3, 84, 
   47, -44, -319, -209}, {-3, 114, 
   64, -67, -434, -274}, {-2, -174, -99, 147, 669, 
   359}, {-2, -144, -82, 124, 554, 294}, {-2, -114, -65, 101, 439, 
   229}, {-2, -84, -48, 78, 324, 164}, {-2, -54, -31, 55, 209, 
   99}, {-2, -24, -14, 32, 94, 34}, {-2, 6, 3, 9, -21, -31}, {-2, 36, 
   20, -14, -136, -96}, {-2, 66, 37, -37, -251, -161}, {-2, 96, 
   54, -60, -366, -226}, {-2, 126, 
   71, -83, -481, -291}, {-1, -162, -92, 131, 622, 
   342}, {-1, -132, -75, 108, 507, 277}, {-1, -102, -58, 85, 392, 
   212}, {-1, -72, -41, 62, 277, 147}, {-1, -42, -24, 39, 162, 
   82}, {-1, -12, -7, 16, 47, 17}, {-1, 18, 10, -7, -68, -48}, {-1, 
   48, 27, -30, -183, -113}, {-1, 78, 44, -53, -298, -178}, {-1, 108, 
   61, -76, -413, -243}, {-1, 138, 
   78, -99, -528, -308}, {0, -150, -85, 115, 575, 325}, {0, -120, -68,
    92, 460, 260}, {0, -90, -51, 69, 345, 195}, {0, -60, -34, 46, 230,
    130}, {0, -30, -17, 23, 115, 65}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 30, 
   17, -23, -115, -65}, {0, 60, 34, -46, -230, -130}, {0, 90, 
   51, -69, -345, -195}, {0, 120, 68, -92, -460, -260}, {0, 150, 
   85, -115, -575, -325}, {1, -138, -78, 99, 528, 308}, {1, -108, -61,
    76, 413, 243}, {1, -78, -44, 53, 298, 178}, {1, -48, -27, 30, 183,
    113}, {1, -18, -10, 7, 68, 48}, {1, 12, 7, -16, -47, -17}, {1, 42,
    24, -39, -162, -82}, {1, 72, 41, -62, -277, -147}, {1, 102, 
   58, -85, -392, -212}, {1, 132, 75, -108, -507, -277}, {1, 162, 
   92, -131, -622, -342}, {2, -126, -71, 83, 481, 291}, {2, -96, -54, 
   60, 366, 226}, {2, -66, -37, 37, 251, 161}, {2, -36, -20, 14, 136, 
   96}, {2, -6, -3, -9, 21, 31}, {2, 24, 14, -32, -94, -34}, {2, 54, 
   31, -55, -209, -99}, {2, 84, 48, -78, -324, -164}, {2, 114, 
   65, -101, -439, -229}, {2, 144, 82, -124, -554, -294}, {2, 174, 
   99, -147, -669, -359}, {3, -114, -64, 67, 434, 274}, {3, -84, -47, 
   44, 319, 209}, {3, -54, -30, 21, 204, 144}, {3, -24, -13, -2, 89, 
   79}, {3, 6, 4, -25, -26, 14}, {3, 36, 21, -48, -141, -51}, {3, 66, 
   38, -71, -256, -116}, {3, 96, 55, -94, -371, -181}, {3, 126, 
   72, -117, -486, -246}, {3, 156, 89, -140, -601, -311}, {3, 186, 
   106, -163, -716, -376}, {4, -102, -57, 51, 387, 257}, {4, -72, -40,
    28, 272, 192}, {4, -42, -23, 5, 157, 127}, {4, -12, -6, -18, 42, 
   62}, {4, 18, 11, -41, -73, -3}, {4, 48, 28, -64, -188, -68}, {4, 
   78, 45, -87, -303, -133}, {4, 108, 62, -110, -418, -198}, {4, 138, 
   79, -133, -533, -263}, {4, 168, 96, -156, -648, -328}, {4, 198, 
   113, -179, -763, -393}, {5, -90, -50, 35, 340, 240}, {5, -60, -33, 
   12, 225, 175}, {5, -30, -16, -11, 110, 110}, {5, 0, 1, -34, -5, 
   45}, {5, 30, 18, -57, -120, -20}, {5, 60, 35, -80, -235, -85}, {5, 
   90, 52, -103, -350, -150}, {5, 120, 69, -126, -465, -215}, {5, 150,
    86, -149, -580, -280}, {5, 180, 103, -172, -695, -345}, {5, 210, 
   120, -195, -810, -410}}
```

I want to select all elements of lst so that GCD equal to 1. For example, with element `{-5, -210, -120, 195, 810, 410}`, I want to get `{-1, -42, -24, 39, 162, 82}`

I tried some elements by hand.

```
1/5*{-5, -210, -120, 195, 810, 410}
```

Comment: I don't understand how you get `{-1, -42, -24, 39, 162, 82}` from `{-5, -210, -120, 195, 810, 410}` by *selecting* elements.  You get that second list by *dividing* the first by 5.  What do you mean by "selecting"?

Comment: Maybe you want to calculate `#/(GCD @@ #) & /@ lst` this is dividing each list by its GCD. But you have lists in `lst` consisting only of zeros. These have to be filtert out before.

Comment: @mgamer You are right.

Comment: @Szabolcs I am sory about my English. mgamer understand me.

Comment: @mgamer Some elements were duplicated.

Comment: @Szabolcs I did as mgamer `#/(GCD @@ #) & /@ lst` this is dividing each list by its GCD. But you have lists in lst consisting only of zeros and some elements were duplicated.

Comment: What do you want to do with zero list and duplicated ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In:

```
 DividedByGCD[xs_] := 
     With[{gcd = GCD[Sequence @@ xs]}, If[gcd == 0, xs, xs/gcd]]
 lst // Map[DividedByGCD]
```